# What is the expectation of the number of failures?

Tags: probability

How can I find the expectation of the number of failures preceding the first success in an infinite series of independent trials with constant probability $p$ of success in each trial?
Thanks.

Comment: If this is HW, please tag it as such.

Comment: No it isn't HW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that it will fail on the first trial is $ 1-p $.

The probability that it will succeed on the first trial but fail on the next is $ p (1-p) $.

The...

The trend here is obvious. Now the expectation will be $ 1 (1-p) + 2 p (1-p) + 3 p^2 (1-p) + 4 p^3 (1-p) + \cdots $.

Now do some footwork with infinite series.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about the geometric distribution?

Alternatively, condition on the result of the first trial.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? >.<